# Docker containers from docker-compose cannot connect to host anymore

Tags: windows, docker, networking, docker-compose, xdebug

I have three services created by a docker-compose running on Windows, and one of them is based on PHP:7.2-apache.
I was able to debug the running application in PHPStorm using XDebug, but since I've duplicated this docker-compose, I cannot anymore.

Here is the value of the XDEBUG_CONFIG var:

```
idekey=phpstorm remote_host=192.168.0.18 remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log remote_port=9000
```

The `remote_host` is the local IP address of the host, as you can see in the result of `ipconfig` (sorry, it is in french):

```
Configuration IP de Windows

Carte Ethernet Ethernet :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : 
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::e5d8:3f1c:32b0:d0ea%13
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.0.18
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Carte Ethernet vEthernet (Commutateur par) 2 :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::b1c1:deaf:a8cd:a9b7%3
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.31.145.129
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
```

XDebug logs these messages:

```
[53] Log opened at 2020-04-30 11:45:11
[53] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.0.18:9000.
[53] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
[53] Log closed at 2020-04-30 11:45:11
```

Executing the `route` command on the container prints this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I don't know what was the default gateway when XDebug worked fine, but is it normal that now this value is the host default gateway ?

Should I configure a network in my docker-compose?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I could resolve my issue.

According to the [Docker for Windows documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host):

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.

So changed the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` variable this way:

```
idekey=phpstorm remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log remote_port=9000
```